# How to access Synology nas available hard disk space through ssh?

Tags: ssh, volume, nas, synology

I recently bought a Synology nas server and installed a 4TB HDD.

Now when accessing the nas through ssh, I checked how much space I have on my root account, and I found out it was only 1.5 GB.

But when I access the Synology nas through the browser, it says I have 3.5 TB available.

Is it possible for me to access this available space through ssh and if not, can I assign 3TB volume for example to my root account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable homes for root ? If so it's still just a subfolder of your volume.

Basically all data is on your volumes, which means accessing via ssh, switching to a root user and `df -h` should give you a correct breakdown of your mounts.

Comment: I did df -h and this is where I got the 1.5 gb left. I am not sure what you mean by enabling home though? I am trying to but I’m not sure how

Comment: GO to NAS DSM -> control panel -> users -> click on "User Home" to enable the home.

Comment: thanks man, now I am able to access the extra storage.